# Solving a PDE for walkSat problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $p(d)= \dfrac{1}{k}p(d-1)+\dfrac{k-1}{k}p(d+1)$

Assuming $p(0)=1$ and $p(\infty)=0$, show that 
$p(d)=(k-1)^{-d}$.

What method do you use to solve these equations?

I'm reading it out of a computational complexity book and it gives no help.

Comment: I assume by LP you meant linear programming. How did you end up tagging this question as (pde) anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are looking to turn this into a linear program.

Assuming that $k\neq 1$, then $(k-1)^{-d}$ clearly satisfies $p(0)=1$ and $p(\infty)=0$. To verify it satisfies the equality just substitute in the terms:

$$p(d-1)=(k-1)^{-d+1}=(k-1)(k-1)^{-d}=(k-1)p(d),$$

$$p(d+1)=(k-1)^{-d-1}=\frac{1}{k-1}(k-1)^{-d}=\frac{1}{k-1}p(d).$$

Hence,

$$\frac{1}{k}p(d-1)+\frac{k-1}{k}p(d+1)=\frac{k-1}{k}p(d)+\frac{1}{k}p(d)=p(d).$$